# jQuery: select elements 1 after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I need to select 4 elements, 1 after the other using their class name. They all have the same class name.

I currently can do this by giving each element an ID like `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth`, etc. But this will make it slightly untidy and I am sure there is a better way of doing this.

This an example of my current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kBJGM/107/

And this is the code I am using:

```
var strokeCount = 0;

$(function(){

    $("#countstroke").keyup(function(){

    var count = ++strokeCount;

    if(count ==1){

    $('#first').css('background','#00a1e8');

    }

    if(count ==2){
    $('#second').css('background','#00a1e8'); 
    }

    if(count ==3){
    $('#third').css('background','#00a1e8');

    }

    if(count ==4){
    $('#forth').css('background','#00a1e8');

    }

    });
});
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Comment: use $('.someclass').eq(count-1).css('background','#00a1e8');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $.eq() for this, so

```
$(".passcircles").eq( count - 1 )
```

Will give you the correct element (the first element is at index 0). So I reckon you want

```
$(".passcircles").eq( count - 1).css("background", "#00a1e8");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `getElementsByClassName`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("passcircles")[count-1].style.background = "#00a1e8";
```

It relies on the class, not the id.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBJGM/111/)

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are defined in a order in the HTML, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.YourClassName')`.

This will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (A list of Nodes, with each node being an element with the class), you can iterate over it similar to an array, and do something like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.YourClassName').forEach(function(node){
  $(node).css('background','#00a1e8');
});
```

Comment: I don't recommend this approach - NodeList is very difficult to work with because it's not a real array.

Comment: @DuncanThacker, difficult depends on the understanding and the requirement, $() also returns nodes!